# Problems with creating custom polyhedron geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

Did adjust `DodecahedronGeometry` to make it a rhombic dodecahedron, all new vertices and faces connected with normals aimed outward
when I tried loading it in `three.js` it did not work.

Any tips or tricks on how to add new shapes to the `three.js` library.

```
/**
* @author Abe Pazos / https://hamoid.com
* @author Mugen87 / https://github.com/Mugen87
*/

import { Geometry } from '../core/Geometry.js';
import { PolyhedronBufferGeometry } from './PolyhedronGeometry.js';

// RhombicDodecahedronGeometry

function RhombicDodecahedronGeometry( radius, detail ) {

  Geometry.call( this );

  this.type = 'RhombicDodecahedronGeometry';

  this.parameters = {
    radius: radius,
    detail: detail
  };

  this.fromBufferGeometry( new RhombicDodecahedronBufferGeometry( radius, detail ) );
  this.mergeVertices();

}

RhombicDodecahedronGeometry.prototype = Object.create( Geometry.prototype );
RhombicDodecahedronGeometry.prototype.constructor = RhombicDodecahedronGeometry;

// DodecahedronBufferGeometry

function RhombicDodecahedronBufferGeometry( radius, detail ) {

  var vertices = [

    // (±1, ±1, ±1)
    - 1, - 1, - 1,  1, - 1, - 1,
    1, - 1, 1,  - 1, - 1, 1,
    - 1, 1, 1,  - 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1,  1, 1, - 1,

    0, 2, 0,  0, - 2, 0,
    0, 0, - 2,  0, 0, 2,
    2, 0, 0,  - 2, 0, 0

  ];

  var indices = [

    0, 3, 13,   9, 3, 0,
    0, 13, 4,  10, 0, 4,
    9, 0, 1,  1, 0, 10,
    7, 10, 4,  4, 8, 7,
    4, 13, 5,  8, 4, 5,
    5, 13, 3,  5, 3, 11,
    3, 2, 11,  3, 9, 2,
    5, 11, 6,  8, 5, 6,
    6, 11, 2,  6, 2, 12,
    12, 7, 6,  7, 8, 6,
    12, 1, 7,  7, 1, 10,
    1, 12, 2,  2, 9, 1

  ];

  PolyhedronBufferGeometry.call( this, vertices, indices, radius, detail );

  this.type = 'RhombicDodecahedronBufferGeometry';

  this.parameters = {
    radius: radius,
    detail: detail
  };

}

RhombicDodecahedronBufferGeometry.prototype = Object.create( PolyhedronBufferGeometry.prototype );
RhombicDodecahedronBufferGeometry.prototype.constructor = RhombicDodecahedronBufferGeometry;


export { RhombicDodecahedronGeometry, RhombicDodecahedronBufferGeometry };
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get an error, a strange result, a black screen...?`

Comment: this post was crossposted oops, sry... i'm new to this asking for help on fora... so it goes further on in the three.js forum, have it working now, yet there is a new issue risen to the surface...

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/problems-with-creating-custom-polyhedron-geometry/5412/14